# DevX GridControl for WinForms - BorderColor

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

DevExpress GridControl control for WinForms supports BorderStyle property (through it's View), but it seems like it doesn't support BorderColor. Or am I wrong?

How can I set BorderColor property for GridControl borders?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You could always set BorderStyle to NoBorder and wrap the GridControl inside a PanelControl.

Set up the properties something like this:

```
gridControl1.MainView.BorderStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.NoBorder;
panelControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
panelControl1.LookAndFeel.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.Flat;
panelControl1.Appearance.BorderColor = Color.Red;
panelControl1.Appearance.Options.UseBorderColor = true;
panelControl1.BorderStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BorderStyles.Simple;
```

Comment: What if you have, say, hundred of GridControl occurences throughout solution? Are you gonna wrap them all?

Comment: It is an alternative. You could make a method that would take a grid and a panel control and setup the properties as described above. Or you could make a UserControl. But then you probably would lose much of the design time features of the grid control which are very nice to have.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to point out that this workaround is not an option in a little more serious scenario and, as you mentioned above, is a metter of compromises. :) That's why I'm sure it must be done through some of GridControl members. I think I'd better contact DevX support team to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using skins? The skinning mechanism will most likely override your border color setting unless you disable them.